# How to edit tiff tags without loading the image into memory

Tags: python, tiff

I am trying to modify the tags of a saved image. In particular I would like to change the pixel resolution tag. I have previously done it with the `tifffile` package by loading the image into memory and then saving the file with the new pixel resolution included as a parameter.

```
from tifffile import TiffWriter:
from imageio import imread
image = imread('image.tif')
with TiffWriter(filename) as tif_w:
    tif_w.write(image,
                resolution=resolution)
```

This method works well, but The image I am reading in is almost 1GB large so this method is rather slow. I am wondering if anyone has a method for simply editing the tag within the save file without rewriting the full file? I have tried the following method using `tifffile.TiffTags`, but I get the following error.

```
import tifffile
import imageio as io
import numpy as np
image = np.zeros(shape=(1000, 1000), dtype=np.uint8)
io.imwrite('image.tif', image)
tiff = tifffile.TiffFile('image.tif', 'wb')
tiff.pages[0].tags['XResolution'].overwrite(tiff, (97321972, 392185))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/home/jed/miniconda3/envs/mcam_dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 7578, in overwrite
    fh.write(struct.pack(tiff.offsetformat, count))
  File "/home/jed/miniconda3/envs/mcam_dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 8939, in write
    return self._fh.write(bytestring)
io.UnsupportedOperation: write
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Use `tiff = tifffile.TiffFile('image.tif', mode='r+b')`

Comment: Thank you! that solves the issue.